iOS 18 tab switch flashes screen
I just noticed when building my app with Xcode 16 (iOS 18) that the screen flashes briefly when switching tabs (using a standard UITabBarController). Have any one of you experienced it? I have searched documentation and can not find anything mentioning changes in the behaviour. I also tried implementing the following methods of UITabBarControllerDelegate:
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, animationControllerForTransitionFrom fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> (any UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning)? {
        nil
    }
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, interactionControllerFor animationController: any UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) -> (any UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning)? {
        nil
    }

How can I get rid of the flashing?


Is this just on simulator or real device as well

Both device and simulator.

May i know device model please?

iPhone 15 PRO Max

Seems to be a bug in iOS 18. I've observed that it goes away when I subclass the embedded UINavigationControllers and put view.backgroundColor = .white into viewDidLoad(). Any color works, but .clear and nil does not.

Temporarily solved it by setting UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false) in func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool
And then setting UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true) in func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController)

Thank you for posting this. Had the same issue here. Very frustrating but your solution looks good.

Hi, I tried it but still doesn't work for me. Should I try setting the delegate programatically?

Objective-C solution for @PeterWarbo's Swift solution.
self.tabBarController.delegate = self;

- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
    return YES;
}

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
}


Peter's solution didn't work for me, but with a little tweak it worked:
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
}


Based on this article, this is a new UITabBarController animation in iOS 18. You can check it in the news app in any simulator running iOS 18.

